# get user input in awk script and update it in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a students.txt (RollNo, Name, IDU, CGPA),  If Roll number exists prompt the user to change the IDU and CGPA and update the same in the file named “Student.txt”

I made the following script:

```
    #! /bin/bash

    dispaly(){
      awk -F ":" -v roll=$1 '{ if ( $1 == roll) {name = $2; print name; } } 
                             END {if (name == "") print "not found" }' students.txt       
    }

    echo "Enter the roll no."
    read rno

    if [ $rno -ge 1000 ] && [ $rno -le 9999 ]
    then
       dispaly $rno
       # Now I have a valid $rno and want to update that line
    else
       echo Enter no between 1000 and 9999
    fi
```

now I need help in taking user input  for IDU and CGPA values and update the students.text file with that values against the record found.

Comment: I think you want a `while` loop until you have a valid `$rno`.

Comment: After reading thenew IDU and CGPA values, try using `awk` or `sed` for replacing field 3 and 4 in the line that starts with $rno. First redirect to another file and when it works, `mv` the new file to the orginal one (or use `sed -i` flag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, I grep for roll

```
grep ^roll students.txt
```

if found then used awk to replace the records

```
awk  -F : -v rno=$rno -v idu=$idu -v cgpa=$cgpa ' $1==rno { $3=idu;$4=cgpa} OFS=":" ' students.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt students.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In general "-" is used for standard input for awk e.g.

```
    awk '{print($1)}' -
```

It's not clear to me exactly what you want here.  Can't you use additional 'read' statements in the bash part of the script for input of the other 2 values?

Comment: actually in awk itself if a rollno. is found  then I want prompt user to enter new IDU and CGPA  values. if no record is found then simply exit awk saying record not found    `awk  '{ if ( $1 == roll) {\\<prompt user for new values>\\ } }'  `